# No Graphics2D.draw method in java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, draw, java-2d

I use NetBeans and the last version of JDK. For some reason there is no `Graphics.draw()` method, though `java.awt.geom.Line2D` and `java.awt.Graphics2D` are imported. How do I draw a `Line2D.Double` element?

```
Shape pLine;
private void playerDraw(){
    Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
    pLine = new Line2D.Double(px, py, Math.cos(angle)*10+px,Math.sin(angle)*10+py);
    g2.drawRect(px-5, py-5, 10, 10);  
    g2.draw(pLine); //this doesn't compile(cannot find symbol)
}
```

Comment: What does getGraphics do? Are you extended an awt class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that you're using a Graphics object as if it were a Graphics2D object, but it's not and as the [Graphics class Java API entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) will show you, the Graphics class does not have a draw method, while [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) does. I think that you're missing a key line, something like:

```
Graphics g = getGraphics();
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; // the missing line
```

But having said that, you are using Graphics incorrectly as you should avoid getting it by calling `getGraphics()` on a Swing component since this gives you an unstable short-lived Graphics object whose use risks causing short-lived images or NullPointerExceptions, but rather you should do your drawing within the JComponent's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to declare pLine variable in your Class:

Eg.

```
public class Example
{

public Line2D.Double pLine;

private void playerDraw(){
    Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
    pLine = new Line2D.Double(px, py,Math.cos(angle)*10+px,Math.sin(angle)*10+py);
    g2.drawRect(px-5, py-5, 10, 10);  
    g2.draw(pLine); //this doesn't compile(cannot find symbol)
}
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, **pLine** is declared as **Shape** outside of the function. Changing it to **Line2D.Double** doesn't change anything.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but declaring a pLine as Line2D.Double doesn't help. I can't access to Graphics.draw() method for some reason.

Comment: @flyer95311 Include in your post the compile error you get, please.

Comment: @flyer95311 Also, be sure the type of variable `pLine` is `java.awt.Shape`.

Comment: @LittleSanti Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.awt.Graphics.draw
 
at prototype.GameLoopIO.writeScreen(GameLoopIO.java:83)
 
at prototype.GameLoopIO.run(GameLoopIO.java:48)
 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: @LittleSanti pLine type is `java.awt.geom.Line2D$Double`